# Checking for updates at startup

Tags: .net, wpf

Let's consider a WPF client-server application.
What is the best practice to create the client, so that every time it is launched, it checks for updates and if any available, update the client application?

Comment: If the user is launching ur application 20 times in a day then it will check for updates 20 times? Sounds funny na? This process clearly means that best practises are not used while programming. Instead I would suggest that the server should inform the client whenever an Update is available.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ClickOnce deployment for your client app, [that should be pretty easy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s22azw1e.aspx).